Msys64/mingw64 trouble, why its 'ln' command did `copy`
On Msys2 env.:
$ cd /c/msys64/mingw64/lib/
$ ln -s libz.dll.a libzlib.dll.a

But confusingly why
ln 

command did copy
instead of linking it symbolically ?
$ ls -l libz*
-rw-r--r-- 1 abdu None 108700 Jan 23  2024 libz.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 abdu None 65914 Jan 23  2024 libz.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 abdu None 65914 Jan 23  2024 libzlib.dll.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 abdu None 2298 Dec 13 03:15 libzoneoc.a

Please one help out of confusion to solution

Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594025/symlink-in-msys2-copy-or-hard-link
